# Return a table that has a specific 'Column Header' from a list of tables in Pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

I have 4x tables (currently) that I need to loop through to find/return the table which has the specific header.

EG. I want to return the data that is in the table with a header called 'Quantity'.

These are the 4x tables in pandas.DataFrame

```
[['', 'Invoice Lines', '', 'Additional', 'Charges', 'Total Invoice', ''], ['', 'Before Tax', '45.45', 'Before Tax', '4.55', 'Before Tax', '50.00'], ['', 'Tax', '4.55', 'Tax', '0.45', 'Tax', '5.00'], ['', 'Total', '50.00', 'Total', '5.00', 'Total', '55.00'], ['', '', '', '', '', 'Payment Total', '55.00'], ['', '', '', '', '', 'Due', '0.00']]

[['#', 'Code', '', 'Product Description', 'Unit', 'Quantity', 'Price', 'Discount', 'Amount', 'Backordered'], ['1', 'GIFTCARD', 'Gift Card', '', 'Xero', '1.00', '50.00', '0.00%', '50.00', 'Yes']]

[['#', 'Description', 'Amount', 'Tax', 'Discount', 'Total'], ['1 Shipping Standard', '', '5.00', '0.45', '0.00%', '5.00']]

[['Payment Method', 'Reference', 'Amount', 'Date', 'Amount'], ['SMB Demo Account', '4772984225836', '55.00', '22/06/2021', '55.00']]
```

All I keep going trying is versions of:

```
for count, table in enumerate(dataframes):
    location = ""
    if table.loc[:,"Quantity"]:
        location += count
```

Trying to get OUTPUT: 1 (for Table #2)

Comment: can you post the table as you have implemented it in the df

Comment: @Panda This is how i built the tables after extract from a json, (https://www.online-python.com/lkX7xczZtI)